# textCapWords attribute doesn't work for Edit Text

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, capitalization

I'm trying to only allow title case in the edit text that I'm coding, but for no reason it doesn't work and the keyboard doesn't capitalize the first character of a word in the edit text automatically.

Here is my code.

Thank You :)

> NOTE: The other attributes such as `textCapCharacters` work.

```
<EditText
            android:id="@+id/typeEditText"
            android:layout_width="284dp"
            android:layout_height="52dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext"
            android:hint="  Type"
            android:imeOptions="actionSend"
            android:inputType="textCapWords"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:textColor="#F0FFFFFF" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it it's from the "class" text as well:

```
   EditText  typeEditText = findViewById(R.id.typeEditText);
   typeEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | 
        InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_SENTENCES);
```

Comment: The same thing here, it started capitalizing all the chars but I only need to cap the first one, so I changed your code from `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTAERS` to `TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_WORDS` and the same thing happened, all the chars are in lower case

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, I thought u want to capitalize all the letters. I updated my answer, hope it helps.